# auth middleware req.body.authorization 'split' is undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, jwt

I am trying to check if there is token but the 'split' is undefined. I'm still learning MERN so idk what's the problem.

```
const auths = async (req,res,next) => {
    try {
        const token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
        const isCustomAuth = token.length < 500;

        let decodedData;

        if(token && isCustomAuth){
            decodedData = jwt.verify(token, 'todo');

            req.userId = decodedData?.id;
        }else {
            decodedData = jwt.decode(token);

            req.userId = decodedData?.sub;
        }

        next();
        console.log('auth tapped!');
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because header don't  have `authorization`. So `req.headers.authorization` is `undefined`. You can use `optional chaining` to fix issues like this:

```
const token = req.headers.authorization?.split(" ")[1];
```

Comment: yes it worked! but the token returned undefined

Comment: Yes. You don't pass `Authorization` in header so it will have not value